# phoenix telemetry monitoring for upstream api calls

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, telemetry

I have the following api client in our phoenix application.

```
defmodule SomeService do
  use HTTPoison.Base


  def process_request_url(url) do
    Application.get_env(:my_app, :some_service)[:host] <> url
  end

  def process_response_body(body) do
    if String.trim(body) != "" do
      body
      |> Poison.decode! # this could fail if the response is html
      |> Enum.map(fn({k, v}) -> {String.to_atom(k), v} end)
      |> Enum.into(%{})
    else
      body
    end
  end

  def get_some_data(customer_id, access_token) do
    path = "/customer/#{customer_id}/"
    headers = [{"Authorization", "Bearer #{access_token}"}]

    case get(path, headers) do
      {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{body: body}} ->
        {:ok, body}
      {:error, error} -> {:error, error}
      _ -> {:error, "unknown error from upstream system"}
    end

  end

end
```

What is the best way to monitor the outgoing API calls ?

- i.e request path, response, time_taken etc

we are using telemetry to monitor incoming requests and ECTO queries. HTTPoison though, doesn't seem to provide telemetry events out of the box, how can we leverage telemetry to achieve this ?

Comment: take a look at this, was released not so long ago exactly for this task https://github.com/beam-telemetry/telemetry

Comment: thanks @Daniel, had followed the same to raise an event after every api call with appropriate handler, but is it the cleanest approach cos if i am adding more api calls to the client, i have to raise the event myself. can this be bettered? Posting my answer below .

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm raising the telemetry event with the response data like below:

```
defmodule SomeService do
  use HTTPoison.Base


  def process_request_url(url) do
    Application.get_env(:my_app, :some_service)[:host] <> url
  end

  def process_response_body(body) do
    if String.trim(body) != "" do
      body
      |> Poison.decode! # this could fail if the response is html
      |> Enum.map(fn({k, v}) -> {String.to_atom(k), v} end)
      |> Enum.into(%{})
    else
      body
    end
  end

  def get_some_data(customer_id, access_token) do
    path = "/customer/#{customer_id}/"
    headers = [{"Authorization", "Bearer #{access_token}"}]

    case get(path, headers) do
      {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{body: body}} ->


        :telemetry.execute(
          [:my_app, :upstream_endpoint],
          %{request_path: response.request_url, 
            status_code: response.status_code, 
            response_headers: response.headers
           },
          response
        )


        {:ok, body}
      {:error, error} -> {:error, error}
      _ -> {:error, "unknown error from upstream system"}
    end

  end

end
```

The response object contains all the information required (url, status, duration etc) to be monitored and this logged in the handler.

```
    def handle_event([:my_app, :upstream_endpoint], measurements, metadata, config) do

        summary_event = []
        |> Keyword.put(:route_url, measurements.request_path)
        |> Keyword.put(:status_code, measurements.status_code)
        |> Keyword.put(:response_headers, Enum.into(measurements.response_headers, %{}))

        Logger.info("upstream-call", summary_event)
    end
```

The event [:my_app, :upstream_endpoint] is attached to the handler in the application start.

```
:telemetry.attach("may-app", [:my_app, :upstream_endpoint], &handle_event/4, %{})
```

Though this works well for now, with every api call the event needs to be raised imperatively, not very extensible.